# How to release mouse in selenium without unexpected shift?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a robot which can help me buy tickets.
Of course there is a drag-captcha. I don't how to write a robot to bypass it. So here is my plan:

1. call `click_and_hold` to the button
2. drag to correct position manually
3. once it's ten o'clock (ticket is for sale on 10 o'clock), call `release` to release mouse

However, when doing step 3, it seems that the mouse will move a random offset shift. How can i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can test this way to make sure you are in the right position:

```
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.clickAndHold(your desired element);
     // wait for clock to become 10
   action.moveToElement(your desired element).release();
   action.build().perform();
```

Comment: cannot do that because i'm trying to slip a scroll-captch. So i don't know `your desired element`